# XOR'ing bytes in a memory dump to check for existance of a key

Tags: python, byte, xor

Reading in a binary file and XORing bytes to find out if there is an AES 128 key present.

```
with open("FakeMemDump1.bin","rb") as memorydump:
    mem = memorydump.read(memorybytes)
    for i in mem:
        w = mem[i]^mem[i+15]
        x = mem[i+4]^mem[i+19]
        y = mem[i+8]^mem[i+23]
        z = mem[i+12]^mem[i+27]
        if w==mem[i+16] and x==mem[i+20] and y==mem[i+24] and z==mem[i+28]:
            keySched = mem[i-1:i+175]
            print ("Key Schedule : "%keySched)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "AES128Keyfind.py", line 8, in <module>
w = mem[i]^mem[i+15]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Above is the error I am receiving, is the byte being called passed in as a string even though the file is read as a binary file?

Comment: Even if were bytes, `for i in mem` iterates over the values, not the indices.

Comment: You want `for i in range(len(mem)):`

Comment: Also, when `i` is greater than `len(mem)-29`, you'll access outside it when you try to access `mem[i+28]`.

Comment: What is `print ("Key Schedule : "%keySched)` supposed to do? You have no formatting operator in the string.